# Oracle 12514 error on linux server

Tags: linux, oracle

I've just download a VM from the oracle and add to virtual box.
When I turn on the oracle, it seems like my listener does not listen to any.
Here are some pictures. Any got a idea on that?

[image: ORACLE 12514]

[image: Listener Support no service]

Comment: I think the problem is regarding the service or `SID`. Make sure you've given correct `SID` in connection parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that symptom if the listener is running but the database instance is not.  Try `ps -ef | grep [o]ra_pmon` and see if you get any results.  You should get one line of output if you have a db instance running.  If not, start the instance:

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba
  ...
SQL> startup
```

Comment: when I enter the sqlplus / as sysdba it says ORA-12514 the same as the pic says and requires a username and password

Comment: @Yuhao_Zhu Weird.  `sqlplus / as sysdba` should try to connect to the (possibly idle) oracle instance using OS authentication and not involve the listener at all, so I don't understand where that ORA-12514 is coming from.  You are doing this on the VM that has the Oracle DB installed?

Comment: Yeah...actually I download the vm directly from the oracle website